# get error starting GeoServer 2.24 and tried 2.26 with mbtiles extension

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I installed both GeoServer 2.24 and 2.26 (one at a time) with the program starting correctly.  Then I added the mbtiles extension files to WEB/lib. (First I loaded the WPS extension).  Then when starting GeoServer I get the following traceback (only the first sections included here...

```
Welcome to GeoServer!

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11

Please wait while loading GeoServer...

2024-03-10 23:10:34.904:INFO::main: Logging initialized @368ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2024-03-10 23:10:35.124:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.52.v20230823; built: 2023-08-23T19:29:37.669Z; git: abdcda73818a1a2c705da276edb0bf6581e7997e; jvm 11.0.21+9-LTS-193
2024-03-10 23:10:35.156:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/] at interval 1
2024-03-10 23:10:36.316:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2024-03-10 23:10:36.347:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2024-03-10 23:10:36.347:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2024-03-10 23:10:36.347:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
23:10:37 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Logging policy: Log4J2
23:10:37 WARN   [geoserver.logging] - Could not find GeoServer logging.xml (or old services.xml) settings for logging
2024-03-10 23:10:37.399:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
23:10:38 WARN   [geoserver.platform] - bean lookup error
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.geoserver.mbtiles.gs.wps.MBTilesProcess] for bean with name 'mbtilesProcess' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-mbtiles-2.26-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geoserver/wps/gs/GeoServerProcess
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:704)
```

Comment: are you sure you matched the version of GeoServer and the plugin exactly?